# Rename files, Python/Jython

Tags: python, file, jython, rename

I have a directory full of files, some which have an ampersand in their names.  I would like to rename all the files with ampersands and replace each ampersand with a plus (+).  I am working with around 10k files.  What would be the best method to do this?

Comment: Is it a flat directory of 10K files, or a directory tree with subdirectories?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import glob, os
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(yourPath, "*&*")):
   os.rename(filename, filename.replace('&','+'))
```

Comment: iglob would be more suitable here

Comment: Took the liberty to change the string-concatenation into a os.path.join() call, for clarity and portability.

Comment: @SilentGhost -- good point, updated.
@unwind -- true, guess I'm to UNIX-centric.

Comment: @vartec: `glob.iglob` is present only in Jython 2.5+ (2.2 lacks it).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: reverted change. I guess it won't mater a lot, 10K names, would occupy at most 2,5MB (more like probable something like 100-200KB).

Answer (score 7):

If you have subdirectories:

```
import os
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(your_path):
    for filename in files:
        if '&' in filename:
            os.rename(
                os.path.join(dirpath, filename),
                os.path.join(dirpath, filename.replace('&', '+'))
            )
```

Comment: What is the point in list comprehension in this case? A simple loop would suffice.

Comment: Does there have to be a point? I might also use a loop here, but the if syntax afterwards seems a bit nicer don't you think?

Comment: 10K list without a reason is the point. Such formatting could lead to bugs e.g., see the comma near `'+')),`.

Comment: +1: for `os.walk` (though OP asks about *single* directory  but in general `os.walk` is preferred).

Comment: btw, jython 2.2 lacks `os.walk` (but jython 2.5 has it).

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
directory = '.'
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if '&' in file :
        os.rename(file, file.replace('&', '+'))
```

Replace `directory` with your own path.

Answer (score 0):

using [rename](https://github.com/75lb/rename):

```
$ rename --find '&' --replace '+' *
```