# Rename files using sub folder names

Tags: python, file, rename

My folder structure is as follows

```
Folder A(Parent folder)

  Folder B(Sub folder)

   1.jpg
   2.jpg
   3.jpg
   4.jpg

  Folder B1(Sub folder)

   1.jpg
   2.jpg
   3.jpg
   4.jpg

  .....

  Folder Bn(Sub folder)

   1.jpg
   2.jpg
   ...jpg
```

How can I rename .jpeg filenames with sub folder names, like this B-1.jpg, B-2.jpg.... and B1-1.jpg, B1-2.jpg... and Bn-1.jpg, Bn-2.jpg ....

My code so far (I have taken the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651712/count-and-print-number-of-files-in-subfolders-using-python):

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
# get all directories
folders = ([name for name in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, name))])
for folder in folders:
  for fname in os.listdir(os.path.join(path,folder)):
    new_fname = os.path.basename(os.path.join(path,folder)) + fname.split('.') **# I think error is in here**
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, fname), os.path.join(path, new_fname))
```

when I run the code, it just shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

I am novice in python, please help and make this complete and perfect, please.

Comment: Look this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641985/rename-files-python-jython?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Completing rocksteady answer, you could use os.walk and os.path.

```
ROOT_DIR=os.getcwd()
for root, dirs, files in os.path.walk(ROOT_DIR):
    dname = os.path.split(root)[-1]
    for file in files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), 
                  os.path.join(root, "{}-{}".format(dname, file))
```

Anyway, the real problem on your code is that "split" there, that outputs **a list**, and you cannot concatenate a list to a string.

Based on your question examples you want this:

```
new_fname = os.path.basename(os.path.join(path,folder)) + fname
```

Answer (score 0):

Take `os.walk('pathToRootDir')`, in order to get sub folders recursively.

In the next step try to debug using print statements like

```
print fname.split('.')
```

You'll find the error yourself, maybe take a deeper look into the split function and try something like:

```
print fname.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Upvoted it. os.walk seems like a logic way to go with that.